# Using the example from the bottle documentation, I still get an empty value for query_string

Tags: python, bottle

Using bottle's built in WSGI server, here is the relevant HTML:

```
form style="display: inline;" action="/forum?id=2&page=5">
        <input type="submit" value="Forum"/></form>
```

Here is the route from my application:

```
@rolodex.route('/forum')
def display_forum():
    forum_id = bottle.request.query.id
    page = bottle.request.query.page or '1'
    return 'Forum ID: %s (page %s)' % (forum_id, page)
```

Here is what I get when I click on the "Forum" button:

Forum ID: (page 1)

Any ideas on what I could possibly be doing wrong?  This is essentially exactly the example found in the documentation:

bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/tutorial.html#request-data

Comment: I should have added: no error messages, or anything like this.  The syntax is slightly different from the example given in the documentation because of this:

    `import bottle`

    `rolodex = bottle.Bottle()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the documentation I've found about this is quite ambiguous, but it appears that most browsers will not process and submit query strings which are appended to <form> actions.  The correct way to do this is to include the query parameters as hidden text fields in the body of the <form> container.  So instead of this:

```
<form style="display: inline;" action="/forum?id=2&page=5">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit"/></form>
```

Do this:

```
<form style="display: inline;" action="/forum">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="5"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

The HTML specification states that a form action must be an HTTP URI, and the definition of URI does include the possibility of a query string; however, if nothing else, it should probably be considered bad form to include the query string variables in the form action when the option of using hidden inputs is a cleaner, less ambiguous solution.

Moreover, as pointed out by Ron Rothman in another answer, there is no reason to use a <form> in this context at all -- just use a link with an appropriate href:

```
<a class="button" href="/forum?id=2&page=5">Edit</a>
```

using this CSS (or something similar):

```
.button {font-size: small;
     font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
     text-decoration: none;
     background-color: #DDDDDD;
     color: #222222;
     padding: 1px 12px 1px 12px;
     border-radius:7px;
     border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
     border-right: 1px solid #333333;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
     border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;}
```

Comment: Wait... I thought that's what my answer said?  :)  Anyway, happy to hear that you're back on track.  Cheers.

Comment: Well, I wanted to make it clear that it appears that browsers don't even send action-attached query strings back to the server, which wasn't in your answer, at least not clearly; and I wanted to summarize everything succinctly in one place.  Other than that, you definitely deserve the credit for pointing out the right way to do this.  I upvoted your answer, but stackexchange only lets me select one answer as the accepted one.  For the sake of completeness I wanted to include both ways of solving this problem (href and hidden fields), since often one does have user-editable form data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the query string in your form action is interacting with the request.  What happens when you make `id` and `page` proper form fields?  Like this:

```
<form action="/forum">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="2"/>
    <input type="text" name="page" value="5"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Forum"/>
</form>
```

(Or, when you hit it with your browser directly?  E.g., `http://yourserver/forum?id=2&page=5`)

Comment: Both of these suggestions work!  This doesn't resolve the mystery of why the request object can't properly parse the form action query string (I've only used this hundreds of times in perl/cgi applications), but setting the input fields to type="hidden" also works, giving me a proper workaround for now.  Thanks!

I'm starting to think that this is a bug, in which case your answer deserves to be checked as the accepted answer.  I'll come back and do that once I hear from Marcel

Comment: Okay, happy to hear it helped. When I'm back at a computer later today I'll look at the source code and try out a thing or two more; I'm not convinced it's a bug in Bottle, but let's see.

Comment: Also, since you just mentioned that you can use hidden fields, I have to ask why you don't just use a link (`<a href`) instead of a form? Your form uses HTTP GET, you already know the values, and you can just style the link as a button if that's a requirement. Just curious, thought I'd ask.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I should just be using a link and not a form for this.  I have no excuse other than force of habit, but have since changed these to be links:

<a class="button" href="/update?rolodex_id={{rolodex_id}}">Edit</a>